# How to fix looping issue, even though no loop implemented?

Tags: c#

Ok, so I am trying to figure out why I am having a looping issue. The intention of the method `GetNewDvdInfo()` is to return a new dvd class with 5 properties and will be passed on to `DvdController.cs` in the `CreateDvd()` method and will then display all the dvds and the dvd the user added. The problem is that the `GetNewDvdInfo()` method is repeating itself, but when I was returning null instead, it was not looping.

**DvdView.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DvdManager.Models;

/* 
    GetMenuChoice() : int
    GetNewDvdInfo(): Dvd
    DisplayDvd(Dvd dvd) : void
    EditDvdInfo(Dvd dvd) : Dvd
    SearchDvd() : int
    ConfirmRemoveDvd(Dvd) : boolean
*/

namespace DvdManager.View
{
    public class DvdView
    {
        public int GetMenuChoice()
        {
            string input;
            int choice;

            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Press 1 to display movies");
            Console.WriteLine("Press 2 to add movie");
            input = Console.ReadLine();

            if (int.TryParse(input, out choice))
            {
                switch (choice)
                {
                    case 1:
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid input");
                        break;
                }

            }
            return choice;


        }

        public Dvd GetNewDvdInfo() //looping here
        {
            string inputReleaseYear;
            string inputRating;

            int id = 4;
            string readTitle;            
            int readReleaseYear;
            string readDirector;            
            float readRating;

            Console.WriteLine("What is the Title of the DVD?");
            readTitle = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("What is the Release Year of the DVD?");
            inputReleaseYear = Console.ReadLine();
            int.TryParse(inputReleaseYear, out readReleaseYear);

            Console.WriteLine("Who is the Director of the DVD?");
            readDirector = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("What is the star rating of the DVD?");
            inputRating = Console.ReadLine();
            float.TryParse(inputRating, out readRating);


            var dvd = new Dvd(id, readTitle, readReleaseYear, readDirector, readRating);
            Dvd newDvd = GetNewDvdInfo();
            return dvd;
        }

        public void DisplayDvd(Dvd dvd)
        {

        }

        public Dvd EditDvdInfo(Dvd dvd)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public int SearchDvd()
        {
            return 0;
        }

        public Boolean ConfirmRemoveDvd(Dvd dvd)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**DvdController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DvdManager.Models;
using DvdManager.Data;
using DvdManager.View;

/* 
    Run() : void
    Private CreateDvd(): void
    Private DisplayDvds(): void
    Private SearchDvds(): void
    Private EditDvd() : void
    Private RemoveDvd() : void
*/

namespace DvdManager.Controllers
{
    public class DvdController
    {
        public DVDList _dvds = new DVDList();        


        public void Run()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome To Dvd Manager");
            DvdView view = new DvdView();

            var pass = view.GetMenuChoice();

            if (pass == 1)
            {
                CreateDvd();
            } 
            else if (pass == 2)
            {
                view.GetNewDvdInfo();
                CreateDvd();
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid.");            
        }

        private void CreateDvd() //Create
        {
            var myView = new DvdView();
            var dvdInfos = myView.GetNewDvdInfo();

            List<Dvd> Dvds = _dvds.GetList();

            Dvds.Add(new Dvd(0, "Batman", 2010, "Bruce", 4));
            Dvds.Add(new Dvd(1, "Superman", 2009, "John", 4));
            Dvds.Add(new Dvd(2, "Wonderwoman", 2012, "Omar", 4));
            Dvds.Add(dvdInfos);


            DisplayDvds();
        }

        private void DisplayDvds() //Read List<Dvd> dvds
        {
            List<Dvd> Dvds = _dvds.GetList();

            for (int i = 0; i < Dvds.Count; i++)
            {                
                Console.WriteLine(Dvds[i]);
            }

            RemoveDvd();
        }

        private void SearchDvds() //List
        {

        }

        private void EditDvd(int id, Dvd dvd) //Update
        {

        }

        private void RemoveDvd() //Delete int id
        {
            List<Dvd> Dvds = _dvds.GetList();

            //Dvds.RemoveAt(Dvds[1]);
            Dvds.Remove(Dvds.Single(x => x.Id == 1));

            Console.WriteLine("Removed movie from list:");

            for (int i = 0; i < Dvds.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Dvds[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: GetNewDvdInfo() calls itself inside the method: `Dvd newDvd = GetNewDvdInfo();`

Comment: `GetNewDvdInfo` calls itself at the end.  What do you expect that to do?

Comment: Actually I was having a looping issue without that as well

Comment: The intention of adding that was because I was told I was not storing a value.

Comment: `else if (pass == 2)` calls `view.GetNewDvdInfo();` and then `CreateDvd();` which calls `view.GetNewDvdInfo();` again.

Comment: You're calling `CreateDvd` for option 1 and option 2. Not this issue you're asking about, but it's still wrong.

Comment: I commented out CreateDVD(); and still looping

Comment: ok I commented out both //CreateDVD(); and //Dvd newDvd = GetNewDvdInfo();, not looping anymore however I am not going to CreateDVD() method anymore.

Comment: ok so I see the problem now, when I call CreateDVD(), I am actually asking the user to add a movie as well.

Comment: Try walking through in the debugger to see what's happening. It's doing exactly what you tell it to. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are making a recursive call at the end of GetNewDvdInfo(), just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling this method recursively here:

```
            var dvd = new Dvd(id, readTitle, readReleaseYear, readDirector, readRating);
            Dvd newDvd = GetNewDvdInfo(); //!!!
            return dvd;
```

Hence the looping. It seems like this line of code is not needed.